# Ionic- Angular : Pass data to a service

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have to pass data to my service and embed it to a url string. Below is how i am receiving data in my constructor while user navigates to the page :

```
  constructor(public alertController: AlertController,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,private ticket_details: TicketDetailsService) {
                this.route.queryParams.subscribe((data)=>{
                  this.id=JSON.stringify(data);
                  alert(this.id);
                });
        }
```

Now here i am calling a service with following code

```
 tcketDetails(){
       this.ticekt_details.get_ticket_details().then(ticketData => {
        console.log(ticketData.data);
        this.ticketData=ticketData.data;
      });

  }
```

**Service Code::**

```
private server_path = 'https://example.com/apis/tickets/ticekt_details/id';

 constructor(private http: HTTP) {  }
 async get_ticket_details() {
    return  this.http.get(this.server_path, {}, {})
      .then(data => {
        return JSON.parse(data.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.status);

      });

  }
```

After receiving id as seen in alert how do I pass id parameter to server_path  variable in my service , Please guide

Comment: You need to be more constructive with your question.
What was the error when you called the service ```get_ticket_details()```?
Also, the service should expect an argument (in this case the id with which you want to get its details)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In constructor of component after this line `this.id=JSON.stringify(data);` when You set Id, call below function to update URL of sertvice like below, You need to add this function in service as well.

In constructor(), call below function to update url..

```
this.id=JSON.stringify(data);
this.ticket_details.updateUrl(id);
```

and then inside `ticket_details` add function definition to update your url before calling get_ticket_details() function.

so updateUrl() function seems like this ...

```
updateUrl(id){
    this.server_path = `this.server_path/ + ${id}`;
}
```

and, at top of your service this.serverUrl should be like below...

```
private server_path = 'https://example.com/apis/tickets/ticekt_details';
```

Now, You can proceed to call `get_ticket_details()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Trying on this

Comment: `this.server_path/ + ${id}`; this prints stirng with this.server_path and json_object ,data is being posted btw